# What is the meaning of "life-compatible hours"?

Tags: meaning

> Base salary of $75,000 USD.
>   Quarterly profit sharing bonuses.
>   Work remotely from anywhere in the world.
>
> **Life-compatible hours**.
>
> Results based culture.
>   3 weeks vacation (2 weeks mandatory).

What is the meaning of this expression?

Comment: It means you can hold this job and still "have a life".

Comment: (1) What @HotLicks said. (2) But you should ask the person who wrote it just what is meant by it. You want to know just what is meant. You don't want to assume more than what they really mean.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it's just another way of saying the job has a good [work-life balance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Work%E2%80%93life_balance). So the (amount of) hours you have to work don't interfere with your private life too much.

Comment: That does seem to conflict with "On call and available 24/7 for any emergencies," though, which is also part of the ad (though not in the question).

Comment: @AndrewLeach true, but every job ad claims it's the best. job. ever.

Comment: The ad is probably not truth-compatible.